# How can I include code in a scaffolding view template in Grails 5?

Tags: grails

I need to import one of my classes in one of my scaffolding views, this used to work in Grails 2 but now appears broken under 5.

I've tried both the GSP and JSP way of importing and both result with the same exception.

The error is as follows..

```
Message
Request processing failed; nested exception is groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed: GStringTemplateScript3.groovy: 3: Unexpected input: '@ page import' @ line 3, column 13. """; @ page import="tst.Customer" ; ^ 1 error
Caused by
Failed to parse template script (your template may contain an error or be trying to use expressions not currently supported): startup failed: GStringTemplateScript3.groovy: 3: Unexpected input: '@ page import' @ line 3, column 13. """; @ page import="tst.Customer" ; ^ 1 error
```

Thank you,

Comment: Can you show the import statement?

Comment: the import was <%@ page import="tst.Customer" %>
thanks